# Xcode's NSlog equivalent under Visual Studio

Tags: windows, visual-studio, xcode, nslog

Under Xcode for MAC, I use NSlog and the Console for debugging.  Is there an equivalent method under Visual Studio under Windows?

Edit:  For completeness, here is what needed

using System.Diagnostics;  //namespace

//to write to debug console
Debug.WriteLine("something goes here");

Also, unlike Apple's NSLog, the Debug.Write only output when the app is built as Debug mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's WinAPI `OutputDebugString` function.

Comment: Still try to figure out why my OutputDebugString does not seem to do anything.  But your answer pointed me to the right direction.

Comment: It works only if the debugger is attached. Or you can use some third-paty apps like DebugView from Sysinternals: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.